# BMS design for 150 A continuous current

Tags: pcb, high-current, bms

I have to design a BMS for a 12s, 1p battery configuration. I am using a [BQ76952](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/bq76952) IC to do voltage measurement and passive balancing. The continuous discharge current is 150 A and peak current is 300 A.

I am not sure how I can design a PCB keeping this in mind. Also, there is a precharge and pre-discharge MOSFET and stuff, but keeping high current in mind I am not sure if I can allow this much current to pass through a PCB. I can't use too many MOSFETs due to size constraints, so I am not sure how to handle this. If anyone has any idea I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried Saturn PCB toolkit? 150 A won't be easy if you are new to electronics.

Comment: No I haven't But I am gonna have a look into that thanks.

Comment: 150A on a single 1p battery cell? Is that even remotely possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. The battery is rated at 6Ah and is capable to supply upto 25C and 50C. Although my requirement is such that I need battery power for like 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some perspective: large companies that specialize manufacturing protector BMSs struggle with products rated for much more than 100 A continuous. That's because that's pretty much the limit for a MOSFET switch and a PCB. Yes, there are a few examples of protector BMSs for 150 A continuous, and one or two for 200 A. But in our experience they have a tendency to melt during actual use.

Given that, I wonder if you somehow have the ability to design a protector BMS for 300 A, when those large companies can't.

If (as I suspect) you don't, then I recommend you reconsider, and instead do what we all do above 100 A: use a contactor instead of MOSFETs.

Comment: Yes that's what I am thinking about using relays instead of mosfet by that way I can mount them on metal plate rather than PCB using wires. But now the problem is they are like 300 dollars!! ;((

Comment: More like $ 20 to 80. https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256801426744533.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US